# Play 2.0 Attempting to obtain a connection from a pool that has already been shutdown

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, akka, ebean

I have AKKA actors running in Play 2 application. There are a list of POJO objects retrieved from database and pass along in a message to actors. When an actor starts processing these objects, it will throw this exception. I guess it tries to read data from DB because of lazy loading of ebean. This happens when running in test cases. I haven't tested in normal application env.

**Attempting to obtain a connection from a pool that has already been shutdown**

```
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.TransactionManager.createQueryTransaction(TransactionManager.java:356)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQueryTransaction(DefaultServer.java:2021)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.OrmQueryRequest.initTransIfRequired(OrmQueryRequest.java:241)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.findList(DefaultServer.java:1468)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultBeanLoader.loadBean(DefaultBeanLoader.java:360)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.loadBean(DefaultServer.java:526)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.loadcontext.DLoadBeanContext.loadBean(DLoadBeanContext.java:143)
at com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept.loadBean(EntityBeanIntercept.java:548)
at com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept.preGetter(EntityBeanIntercept.java:638)
at models.MemberInfo._ebean_get_type(MemberInfo.java:4)
at models.MemberInfo.getType(MemberInfo.java:232)
at actors.MessageWorker.doSendToIOS(MessageWorker.java:161)
at actors.MessageWorker.onReceive(MessageWorker.java:97)
at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(UntypedActor.scala:154)
at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(UntypedActor.scala:153)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:311)
at akka.actor.UntypedActor.apply(UntypedActor.scala:93)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:619)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:196)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:178)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:505)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Comment: Akka will serialize the actor's state.  Do you need this part of the app to be stateful?  If not, then maybe it's better to use something other than actors.

Comment: Do you mean I should not use actor to connect to DB?

Comment: You definitely can connect to a DB from an Actor if you want.  It looks like from your stacktrace that it's not serialization that is hitting the lazy property, but rather something in the `MemberInfo.getType` method.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes. But this is in the test case env. I am not sure what is different in play 2.0 tests.

Comment: If you force eager loading in EBean does it work normally?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure if it's relevant for you, I'll tell my story. I had the same error message coming up when running my test-cases, without using actors.

First note that, during stopping a Play application, its data-sources are closed.

Since many of my test-cases require a running `Application` in scope, I was using the `WithApplication` helper around each test-case. The problem in my case was that my DB-access object was a singleton (a Scala `object`) initializing its `Datasource` only once. Since that object was never re-instantiated between test-cases, the closed datasource remained there, resulting in the mentioned error.

The solution in my case was to make sure the datasource was re-created between test-cases.